# How to renew access token with the refresh token in oauth2 in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am very new to spring and it is my first attempt at spring security with oauth2. I have implemented OAuth2 with spring security and I do get the access token and the refresh token. However, while sending the refresh token to get the new access token I got "o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint - IllegalStateException, UserDetailsService is required."

The solution to similar problem by other users appeared to be attaching UserDetailsService with the endpoint.

So I did the same and now when I try to send the request to with grant_type: refresh_token and refresh_token: THE TOKEN along with the client id and secret, I get an error that the user was not found.

Please refer the WebSecurityConfiguration class below:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

     @Bean
     @Override
     public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean ();
     }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
     protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
     }

    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Please refer the AuthorizationServerConfiguration class below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired 
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore());
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);  
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Please refer the ResourceServerConfiguration class below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() { 
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("scout").tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
         .authorizeRequests (). antMatchers ("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize **").permitAll();  
         // .anyRequest (). authenticated (); 
         http.requestMatchers (). antMatchers ("/api/patients/**") // Deny access to "/ private"
         .and (). authorizeRequests ()
         .antMatchers ("/api/patients/**"). access ("hasRole ('PATIENT')") 
         .and (). requestMatchers (). antMatchers ("/api/doctors/**") // Deny access to "/ admin"
         .and (). authorizeRequests ()
         .antMatchers ("/api/doctors/**"). access ("hasRole ('DOCTOR')");
    }
}
```

The CustomUserDetailsService class for reference if required:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Optional<Users> usersOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        Users user = null;

        if(usersOptional.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(usersOptional.isPresent());
            user = usersOptional.get();
        }else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Email is not registered!");
        }

        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }

}
```

As I think, the server should only check for the validity of the refresh token as we don't pass the user details with refresh token. So I don't know why it requires the userDetails in the first place.

Please help and guide if I am missing something!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi rajjputh did you find a solution for this? I am also getting this error for the request http://localhost:8081/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=e85083dd-22e2-48fb-9e63-04eb9df90e25

Comment: I couldn't figure out the issue with this implementation. So I followed another tutorial, tested it and then replaced this one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure. But as I see your code in WebSecurityConfiguration could wired default InMemoryUserDetailsManager UserDetailsService .That could be reason why you have 2 different provider. In one you write, from the other you read users. Please try change your code as I show below and let me know if it help:

Was:

```
@Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
```

My vision how should be:

```
@Autowired
   private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
```

Comment: CustomUserDetailsService  implements UserDetailsService , therefore I guess it will  automatically call CustomUserDetailsService . However, I tried your code and same error. It could not find the user when refreshing the token.