# Error persisting OAuth2AutorizedClient in Spring Security 5 with JdbcOauth2AuthorizedClientService

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to use `JdbcOauth2AuthorizedClientService` to persist the authorized client info such as `access_token` and `refresh_token` in a Stateless microservice. I'm getting below error, I never get to resolve the required resource and authorized client info never gets saved in Postgres.

> [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to
> retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 500 Internal Server
> Error: "{"timestamp":1672302575797,"status":500,"error":"Internal
> Server
> Error","exception":"org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException","message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Unsupported contentType: application/json","path":"/oauth2-v1/oauth2/token"}"
> [image]

Interestingly, when I use the `InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService` implementation OAuth2 flow works fine. Error message doesn't look has anything to do with JDBC/DB connection.

I decided to use this implementation per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61565214/7170685)

I'm using the Postgres schema version for table `oauth2_authorized_client`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE oauth2_authorized_client (
  client_registration_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  principal_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  access_token_type varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  access_token_value bytea NOT NULL,
  access_token_issued_at timestamp NOT NULL,
  access_token_expires_at timestamp NOT NULL,
  access_token_scopes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  refresh_token_value bytea DEFAULT NULL,
  refresh_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (client_registration_id, principal_name)
);
```

I have tried the following:

1. Read `LobHandler` interface documentation where it states that different database drivers will behave differently with regards to BLOB data type handling, so in my case, for Postgres, they recommend:

- Creating a `DefaultLobHandler` with `wrapAsLob = true`

Comment: Have you tried changing `access_token_value` and `refresh_token_value` type to `text` from `bytea` in your schema?

Comment: @Elyorbek Yes, just tried that and still get the same error. It's interesting that error states that the internally created endpoint `/oauth2-v1/oauth2/token` doesn't accept `application/json` Content-Type, which to me is unrelated to use a different service implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with the following:

- A small detail that I didn't mention is that I'm using `LiquidBase` for schema migrations in my project, so `Liquibase` Spring Boot auto configuration automatically creates schema for me from the schema definitions `YAML/XML`.
- I removed my previously created table `oauth2_authorized_client`
- I changed my LiquiBase schema definition to remove `access_token_value` -> `NOT NULL` constraint and used `DEFAULT NULL` (same as `refresh_token_value`).
- I ran again the application and this time it worked

Apparently, `JdbcOauth2AuthorizedClientService` tries to insert an entry with `access_token_value` null at some point in the flow...